# How to create a model with ManyToOne like fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out how to properly create a model which has to have two attributes (Models) and it should meet some conditions.

So the model is called `Job`.

The `Job` represents buying a translation from one language (model `Language`) to another language (model `Language` too).

Each `Job` have to have exactly 1 `language_from` attribute and exactly 1 `language_to` attribute.

My old models:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders')
    translator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='jobs',null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)

    language_from = # Didn't know what to put here
    language_to = # Didn't know what to put here   

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.customer,)
```

I was searching for a way how to make it work, I though about some `ManyToOne` field but I've realised that there is no such field. So I've been adviced to rebuilt my models this way:

> There will be no `language_from` and `language_to` attributes in Job.
>   There will be `to` and `from` attributes in model `Language` which
>   will be `ForeignKey`s.

So the `Job` would not have `language_from/to` attributes, instead of that, there would be attributes in `Language` model:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    job_from = models.ForeignKey('Job',related_name='language_form',null=True)
    job_to = models.ForeignKey('Job',related_name='language_to',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This way probably would work correctly but there are many problems.

1. I can't tell the Django that every Job has to have exactly on
   `language_form` and `language_to`
2. There are problems when trying to create a `JobCreationForm` because I can't add `language_from/to` fields inside a `class Meta:`
3. I think that it is not intuitive and there will be more problems which I don't know yet about

.

```
class JobCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Specification'}))
    file = forms.FileField()


    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'language_from','language_to', 'description', 'file', 'specialist'
        )
```

> > > Exception Value: 
> > >       Unknown field(s) (language_from, language_to) specified for Job

Do anybody knows what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't use related name in your fields().
So change

```
    fields = (
        'language_from','language_to', 'description', 'file', 'specialist'
    )
```

into

```
    fields = (
        'job_from','job_to', 'description', 'file', 'specialist'
    )
```

Next, if you want to have for each job a language from & a language to, these are mandatory fields, so you can do this:

```
job_from = models.ForeignKey('Job',related_name='language_form')
job_to = models.ForeignKey('Job',related_name='language_to')
```

(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required)